# Icon for language input method selection missing

Tags: keyboard

I am using elementary os 0.3.2 (Freya 64-bit), and install English and Chinese language packages. However, I can't find keyboard input method selection icon on the system settings. How can I choose input method for Chinese and make the input method start automatically and it's icon stay on system notice bar?

Thanks
Athens Yan